# Roth IRA conversion and income limit

Tags: ira, income, limits

If I convert some amount to Roth IRA from traditional IRA, I understand that this will get added to MAGI and I will have to pay taxes on this amount. My husband and I file tax jointly. Will this affect next year’s Roth IRA contribution for him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the Roth IRA income limit for contributions is based on current year MAGI. The previous year's MAGI has no impact.

Comment: And moreover, the income from conversions is not included in the MAGI that is used for determining the Roth IRA contribution limit, so it does not affect how much can be contributed to this year's Roth IRA either.

Comment: @user102008 Somehow I had never heard this, but I looked up the [worksheet for Roth IRA MAGI](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590a#en_US_2020_publink100025085), and sure enough, there it is.

Comment: I understand that the conversion amount is treated as taxable income and I have to pay federal tax on it. Do I have to pay state tax too?

Comment: @user65985 In almost every state with an income tax, yes. Pennsylvania doesn't tax conversions, and there may be a few more states like that.